# What is being passed in?

Tags: haskell, syntax

In the code:

```
oneChar :: Char -> Doc
oneChar c = case lookup c simpleEscapes of
              Just r -> text r
              Nothing | mustEscape c -> hexEscape c
                       | otherwise   -> char c
    where mustEscape c = c < ' ' || c == '\x7f' || c > '\xff'

simpleEscapes :: [(Char, String)]
simpleEscapes = zipWith ch "\b\n\f\r\t\\\"/" "bnfrt\\\"/"
    where ch a b = (a, ['\\',b])
```

r isn't being passed to oneChar. Where does r come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lookup c simpleEscapes` returns a `Maybe String` value, which can be either `Nothing` or `Just <a string>`. `r` is the string contained in the `Just`, as defined by the line:

```
Just r -> text r
```

Answer (score 3):

The case keyword introduces a pattern match, which has the form `case EXPR of (PATTERN -> EXPR)+`. So `Just r` is a pattern, that matches the result of `lookup c simpleEscapes of`. In a pattern, variables can be bound. Basically this means, if `lookup c simpleEscapes of` returns a `Just` then `r` will be bound to the value inside that `Just` and the result of the expression will be `text r`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking where the identifier is introduced, it's bound by the *pattern match* in the `case` statement, the same way the identifier `c` is bound by the pattern match in the function definition.

Any pattern match can introduce a new identifier for the associated expression:

```
(\(Just x) -> x) foo

let (Just x) = foo in x

f (Just x) = x

case foo of 
    Just x -> x
```

...all of those introduce a new identifier named `x`. In fact, they're all pretty much equivalent, because the compiler converts all of them into `case` blocks under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a case statement on the value returned by lookup c simpleEscapes, which is of type Maybe. Maybe has two data constructors: Just and Nothing. The Just data constructor is parameterized by one value, the Nothing data constructor has no parameters.

So in this case, r is the formal parameter to the Just data constructor: its the actual value in the returned value from lookup.